# Calculate the memory and CPU utilization for pods by Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to find the sutiable expression to set alert that can calculate the Pods utlization  that are reaching 80%  for both memory and CPU on all the pods that are exisiting  on namespace so i appreciate if can someone help me to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

The Kubernetes ecosystem includes two complementary add-ons for aggregating and reporting valuable monitoring data from your cluster: Metrics Server and kube-state-metrics.

[Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) collects resource usage statistics from the kubelet on each node and provides aggregated metrics through the [Metrics API](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics). Metrics Server stores only near-real-time metrics in memory, so it is primarily valuable for spot checks of CPU or memory usage, or for periodic querying by a full-featured monitoring service that retains data over longer timespans.

**kube-state-metrics** is a service that makes cluster state information easily consumable. Whereas Metrics Server exposes metrics on resource usage by pods and nodes, kube-state-metrics listens to the Control Plane API server for data on the overall status of Kubernetes objects (nodes, pods, Deployments, etc.), as well as the resource limits and allocations for those objects. It then generates metrics from that data that are available through the Metrics API.

Once you have installed the same, you can use the following command to get the metrics

```
kubectl top pod <pod-name> -n <namespace> --containers
```